# Clicking on a ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a `ListView` with a header and a footer. I added two items with a class of my own extending the `ArrayAdapter` class. In this extended class, I have overridden the `getView` function because I want `View`s which are not `TextView`s to appear in my `ListView`.

On this `ListView`, I have set an `onClickListener`.

The problem is that this `onClickListener` is started when I click either on the header or on the footer, but never when I click on my items.

Of course, the `View` returned by `getView` is set to be clickable.

What am I missing?

Comment: remove this "Of course, the View returned by getView is set to be clickable." and setOnItemClickListener...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found : the click listener attached to the 'ListView' is only used for the clicks on the header and the footer. For my custom rows, in my ArrayAdapter's 'getView' function, I attached one listener to the 'TextView' and another to the 'ImageButton'.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to do something different when each list element is clicked? If so, you should programmatically set an onClickListener for each of those 2 elements added. Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are making this much more complicated than necessary. You can create your own layout for each row of a `ListView` using an XML file. This allows you to use any combinations of `View`s that you wish. To control what happens when the user clicks on a row in the `ListView`, your activity class should extend `ListActivity` and override `onItemClickListener()`. Alternatively, you can call `setOnItemClickListener()` on your `ListView`. For more details, I suggest that you read [the Android ListView Developer Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html).

Comment: The 'View's I create in my 'ArrayAdapter' are already described in an XML file. In my 'getView' function, I inflate the XML file to get my 'View'. And, as said in my question, I already called 'setOnClickListener' for my 'ListView'. The problem is that only clicks on the header and the footer are activating this listener... And, unfortunately, the Android ListView developer's guide doesn't help me finding the cause of the problem.

Comment: @Zelig63 What functionality are you adding to `ArrayAdapter` that requires you to extend it?

Comment: I subclasse the 'ArrayAdapter' to display 'View's which are not 'TextView's, as it is said in the 'ArrayAdapter' class description : "To use something other than TextViews for the array display, for instance, ImageViews, or to have some of data besides toString() results fill the views, override getView(int, View, ViewGroup) to return the type of view you want."

Comment: @Zelig63 Gotchya. So do you want the whole row to be clickable or individual views in each row?

Comment: My 'View' is composed of two items : a 'TextView' and an 'ImageButton'. When the 'TextView' is clicked, I want it's text to be edited. When the 'ImageButton' in clicked, I want the row to be deleted.

Comment: @Zelig63 Then you need to set individual `ClickListener`s to each `TextView` and `ImageButton` rather than just one on the whole `ListView`.